# BringToFront Force Closes the application

Tags: java, android, layout, android-relativelayout

Here is the code i have problem with 
Here is complete code

```
public class CameraFragment extends Fragment implements OrientationListener {

private Camera mCamera;
private CameraPreview mPreview;
FrameLayout previewFrameLayout;
private Button cameraButton;
private Button cancelButton;
private Button addButton;
private Button retakeButton;
private Button doneButton;

//coach mark variable
private boolean cocahMarkVisible=true;
private RelativeLayout coachMarkTopLayout;
private TextView coachText;
private ImageView arrowImage;

private LinearLayout cameraPreviewCenterTop;
private LinearLayout cameraPreviewCenterBottom;

private LinearLayout cameraBtnLayout;
private LinearLayout addSectionBtnLayout;

private LinearLayout receiptPreviewLayout;
private ImageView receiptPreviewImage;

private TextView receiptPreviewLabelText;
private TextView cameraPreviewLabelText;

private LinearLayout keepFlatLayout;
private TextView keepFlatTxt;

private TextView receiptEdgeLeft;
private TextView receiptEdgeRight;

private LinearLayout headerView;
private TextView headerTextView;


private boolean cameraFlat = false;
private boolean addSectionDisplayed = false;
private boolean orientationListenerEnabled = true;

private String lastImageFile;

private List<String> imgPaths = new ArrayList<String>();

private static int MAX_NUM_OF_RECEIPTS = 5;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false);
    //View view2 = inflater
        //  .inflate(R.layout.camera_coachmark, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setupViews();

    //showInstructionsDialog(false);

}

private void setupViews() {

    RelativeLayout fragmentLayout = (RelativeLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.CameraFragmentLayout);
    ImageUtils.fixBackgroundRepeat(fragmentLayout);

    // Create an instance of Camera
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();
    setCameraParams(mCamera);

    // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(getActivity(), mCamera);
        previewFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        previewFrameLayout.addView(mPreview);


    setView();

    //coachMarkTopLayout = (RelativeLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.coach_mark_top_layout);
    //coachMarkTopLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //coachMarkTopLayout.bringToFront();

    //to start make receipt preview hided
    if(receiptPreviewLayout != null) {
        receiptPreviewLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        addSectionBtnLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        cameraBtnLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        addSectionDisplayed = false;
        keepFlatLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        keepFlatLayout.bringToFront();
        keepFlatTxt.setText(R.string.camera_keep_straight);
        keepFlatTxt.bringToFront();
        if(cocahMarkVisible == true)
        {
            coachMarkTopLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            coachMarkTopLayout.bringToFront();
        }
    }

    //coachMarkTopLayout.bringToFront();

    headerView = (LinearLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.message_header_layout_id);
    headerTextView = (TextView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.message_header_textview);

    if(NetworkHelper.isOffline(getActivity())) {            
        enableHeaderAndFooter(R.string.offerslist_no_internet);
    } else {
        disableHeaderAndFooter();
    }

}


protected void enableHeaderAndFooter(int msgId) {
    headerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    headerTextView.setText(msgId);
    headerView.bringToFront();
}

protected void disableHeaderAndFooter() {
    headerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);        
}

private void setCameraParams(Camera mCameraInstance) {
    if (mCamera == null)
        return;

    // set orientation
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

    // set Camera parameters
    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();

    // following is supported only from android 4.0
    /*
     * if (params.getMaxNumMeteringAreas() > 0){ // check that metering
     * areas are supported List<Camera.Area> meteringAreas = new
     * ArrayList<Camera.Area>();
     * 
     * Rect areaRect1 = new Rect(-100, -100, 100, 100); // specify an area
     * in center of image meteringAreas.add(new Camera.Area(areaRect1,
     * 600)); // set weight to 60% Rect areaRect2 = new Rect(800, -1000,
     * 1000, -800); // specify an area in upper right of image
     * meteringAreas.add(new Camera.Area(areaRect2, 400)); // set weight to
     * 40% params.setMeteringAreas(meteringAreas); }
     */

    List<String> focusModes = params.getSupportedFocusModes();

    if (focusModes != null &&  focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO)) {
        params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
    }

    mCamera.setParameters(params);

}

private void cancelButtonPress() {
    cancelButton.setEnabled(false);
    getActivity().finish();
}


private void cameraButtonPress() {
    cameraButton.setEnabled(false);


    // only process if camera is flat
    if (cameraFlat) {
            orientationListenerEnabled = false;
            enableAquiringFocus(R.string.camera_acquire_focus);
            mCamera.autoFocus(myAutoFocusCallback);
    }

}

private void afterPictureTaken() {

    try {
        if(mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        Log.e(Constant.CARTPERK_LOG_TAG, "Not able to stop preview after picture taken");
    }


    orientationListenerEnabled = true;
    keepFlatLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    cameraBtnLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    addSectionBtnLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);        
    retakeButton.setEnabled(true);
    addButton.setEnabled(true);
    doneButton.setEnabled(true);

    addSectionDisplayed = true;

    if(this.imgPaths.size() >= MAX_NUM_OF_RECEIPTS) {
        addButton.setEnabled(false);
    }

    //cameraPreviewCenterTop.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(R.color.camera_screen_bg_color));
    cameraPreviewCenterTop.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.camera_screen_bg_color));


}



private void retakeButtonPress() {

    retakeButton.setEnabled(false);
    addButton.setEnabled(false);
    doneButton.setEnabled(false);

    addSectionDisplayed = false;

    // remove last stored path
    if (imgPaths.size() > 0) {
        imgPaths.remove(imgPaths.size() - 1);
    }

    //if there are no images, then remove receipt preview
    if(imgPaths.size() == 0) {
        receiptPreviewLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    addSectionBtnLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    cameraBtnLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    cameraButton.setEnabled(true);
    orientationListenerEnabled = true;
    keepFlatLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    cameraPreviewLabelText.setText(String.valueOf(1 + imgPaths.size()));


    cameraPreviewCenterTop.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.camera_screen_bg_semi_color));

    mCamera.startPreview();

}

private void addSectionButtonPress() {
    retakeButton.setEnabled(false);
    addButton.setEnabled(false);
    doneButton.setEnabled(false);

    addSectionDisplayed = false;

    receiptPreviewLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    receiptPreviewLabelText.setText(String.valueOf(imgPaths.size()));

    // show portion of existing receipt

    // show image
    if (lastImageFile != null) {
         Bitmap lastRcptBitmap = ImageUtils.createScaledRotatedGreyedImage(lastImageFile, getActivity(), 90f);

         Bitmap croppedBitmap = ImageUtils.croppedImageForImageView(lastRcptBitmap);
         Bitmap frameWidthAdjustedImage = ImageUtils.adjustFrameLayoutWidthWithZoom(croppedBitmap);
         receiptPreviewImage.setImageBitmap(frameWidthAdjustedImage);                     
         receiptPreviewImage.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    }

    addSectionBtnLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    cameraBtnLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    cameraButton.setEnabled(true);
    orientationListenerEnabled = true;
    keepFlatLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    cameraPreviewLabelText.setText(String.valueOf(1 + imgPaths.size()));



    cameraPreviewCenterTop.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.camera_screen_bg_semi_color));

    // start preview
    mCamera.startPreview();

}

private void doneButtonPress() {
    retakeButton.setEnabled(false);
    addButton.setEnabled(false);
    doneButton.setEnabled(false);

    orientationListenerEnabled = false;

    enableAquiringFocus(R.string.camera_process_receipts);

    submitPictures();

}

public void onReceiptHandlerError() {

    //keepFlatLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);       
    orientationListenerEnabled = true;


    retakeButton.setEnabled(true);
    addButton.setEnabled(true);
    doneButton.setEnabled(true);
}

public LinearLayout getKeepFlatLayout() {
    return this.keepFlatLayout;
}


private void setView() {
    cameraButton = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btn_camera);
    cancelButton = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
    addButton = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
    retakeButton = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btn_retake);
    doneButton = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btn_done);

    cameraPreviewCenterTop = (LinearLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.camera_preview_center_top_area);
    cameraPreviewCenterBottom = (LinearLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.camera_preview_center_bottom_area);

    cameraBtnLayout = (LinearLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btn_camera_layout);
    addSectionBtnLayout = (LinearLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btn_add_section_layout);

    receiptPreviewLayout = (LinearLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.receipt_preview_area);
    receiptPreviewImage = (ImageView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.camera_receipt_image);

    receiptPreviewLabelText = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.receipt_preview_label1);
    cameraPreviewLabelText = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.camera_preview_label1);

    keepFlatLayout = (LinearLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.keep_flat_layout);
    keepFlatTxt = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.keep_flat_label);

    receiptEdgeLeft = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.camera_receipt_edge_label1);
    receiptEdgeRight = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.camera_receipt_edge_label2);

    coachMarkTopLayout = (RelativeLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.coach_mark_top_layout);
    coachText = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.coach_mark_add_msg);
    arrowImage = (ImageView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.arrow_camera_msg);

    cameraButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cameraButtonPress();
        }
    });

    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cancelButtonPress();
        }
    });

    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addSectionButtonPress();
        }
    });

    retakeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            retakeButtonPress();
        }
    });

    doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            doneButtonPress();
        }
    });


}

private void submitPictures() {

    if(FacebookHelper.isUserLoggedIn(getActivity().getApplicationContext())) {
        ReceiptHandler receiptHandler = new ReceiptHandler(this.imgPaths, this.getActivity().getApplicationContext());      
        receiptHandler.submitAnduploadReceipt();


        //show dialog with message, receipt submission in background
        keepFlatLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        showDialog(R.string.camera_receipt_in_background, true, null);
    } else {
        previewFrameLayout.removeView(mPreview);
        previewFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        Intent intentLogin = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
        intentLogin.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intentLogin.putExtra("AFTER_LOGIN_STEP", Constant.AFTER_LOGIN_CAMERA);
        startActivityForResult(intentLogin, Constant.REQUEST_CODE_FROM_CAMERA);
    }

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(Constant.CARTPERK_LOG_TAG, "=================requestCode==="+requestCode+"==========resultCode="+resultCode);

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == Constant.REQUEST_CODE_FROM_CAMERA) {

        previewFrameLayout.removeView(mPreview);
        previewFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d(Constant.CARTPERK_LOG_TAG, "========Inside RESULT_OK=========requestCode==="+requestCode+"==========resultCode="+resultCode);

            try {
                if(mCamera != null) {
                    mCamera.stopPreview();
                }
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                Log.e(Constant.CARTPERK_LOG_TAG, "Not able to stop preview after picture taken");
            }


            ReceiptHandler receiptHandler = new ReceiptHandler(this.imgPaths, this.getActivity().getApplicationContext());      
            receiptHandler.submitAnduploadReceipt();

            //show dialog with message, receipt submission in background
            keepFlatLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //showDialog(R.string.camera_receipt_in_background, true, null);
        } else {
            Log.d(Constant.CARTPERK_LOG_TAG, "========Inside not RESULT_OK=========requestCode==="+requestCode+"==========resultCode="+resultCode);

            try {
                if(mCamera != null) {
                    mCamera.stopPreview();
                }
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                Log.e(Constant.CARTPERK_LOG_TAG, "Not able to stop preview after picture taken");
            }

            keepFlatLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //showDialog(R.string.camera_receipts_error, true, null);

        }
    }



}


private boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
    if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
            PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
        // this device has a camera
        return true;
    } else {
        // no camera on this device
        return false;
    }
}

/** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}

private void releaseCamera() {
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.release(); // release the camera for other applications
        mCamera = null;

        previewFrameLayout.removeView(mPreview);
        mPreview = null;
    }

}

private void resumeCamera() {
    if (mCamera == null) {
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        setCameraParams(mCamera);

        mPreview = new CameraPreview(getActivity(), mCamera);
        previewFrameLayout.addView(mPreview);

    }
}

private void takePicture() {

    // get an image from the camera
    // mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
    mCamera.takePicture(myShutterCallback, myPictureCallback_RAW, mPicture);

}

AutoFocusCallback myAutoFocusCallback = new AutoFocusCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onAutoFocus(boolean arg0, Camera arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        takePicture();
    }
};

ShutterCallback myShutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onShutter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};

PictureCallback myPictureCallback_RAW = new PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};

private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        File pictureFile = ImageHelper.getOutputMediaFile(ImageHelper.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        if (pictureFile == null) {
            Log.d(Constant.CARTPERK_LOG_TAG,
                    "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");
            return;
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d(Constant.CARTPERK_LOG_TAG,
                    "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(Constant.CARTPERK_LOG_TAG,
                    "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        Log.d(Constant.CARTPERK_LOG_TAG, "==================myPicture=======");
        // mCamera.startPreview();

        lastImageFile = pictureFile.getAbsolutePath();
        imgPaths.add(lastImageFile);

        afterPictureTaken();

    }
};


/** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
    return Uri.fromFile(ImageHelper.getOutputMediaFile(type));
}





private void enableAquiringFocus(int messageId) {
    keepFlatLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    keepFlatTxt.setText(messageId);

}

private void disableAquiringFocus() {


}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    //resumeCamera
    resumeCamera();

    boolean isOrientationSupported = OrientationManager.isSupported(); 

    //for testing
    //isOrientationSupported = false;

    if (isOrientationSupported) {
        OrientationManager.startListening(this);
    } else {
        //mark it as flat always
        cameraFlat = true;
        //show same message
        keepFlatTxt.setText(R.string.camera_keep_straight);
    }
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (OrientationManager.isListening()) {
        OrientationManager.stopListening();
    }

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    releaseCamera(); // release the camera immediately on pause event
}

@Override
public void onOrientationChanged(float azimuth, float pitch, float roll) {
    // to show actual values
}

@Override
public void onBottomUp() {
    // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Bottom UP", 1000).show();
}

@Override
public void onLeftUp() {
    // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Left UP", 1000).show();
}

@Override
public void onRightUp() {
    // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Right UP", 1000).show();
}

@Override
public void onTopUp() {
    // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Top UP", 1000).show();
}

@Override
public void onNotFlat() {
    cameraFlat = false;


    if(orientationListenerEnabled) {
        cameraButton.setEnabled(false);
    if (!addSectionDisplayed) {
        keepFlatTxt.setText(R.string.camera_keep_straight);
        keepFlatLayout.bringToFront();
        keepFlatTxt.bringToFront();
    }
    }

    if(this.imgPaths.size() >= MAX_NUM_OF_RECEIPTS) {

    }

}

@Override
public void onFlat() {
    if(orientationListenerEnabled) {
        cameraFlat = true;
        cameraButton.setEnabled(true);
        keepFlatTxt.setText(R.string.camera_is_straight);
        keepFlatLayout.bringToFront();
        keepFlatTxt.bringToFront();
    }


    if(this.imgPaths.size() >= MAX_NUM_OF_RECEIPTS) {

    }

}
```

and the logcat is as shown below if i remove the that bringtofront line everything works fine

```
03-25 08:57:00.184: D/CARTPERK APP(7910): ====OfferItemMain==Inside     setOfferMain====0=====Oats Idli
03-25 08:57:00.184: D/CARTPERK APP(7910): =======Inside OffersGridView getView step4======0
03-25 08:57:00.184: D/CARTPERK APP(7910): ==================Inside loadDataForScrollDown==============
03-25 08:57:00.184: I/Pontiflex SDK(7910): No storage file found
03-25 08:57:00.364: D/AndroidRuntime(7910): Shutting down VM
03-25 08:57:00.364: E/AndroidRuntime(7910): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-25 08:57:00.364: E/AndroidRuntime(7910): Process: com.cartperk.android.cartperk, PID: 7910
03-25 08:57:00.364: E/AndroidRuntime(7910): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   ComponentInfo{com.cartperk.android.cartperk/com.cartperk.android.cartperk.ui.CameraActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RelativeLayout.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
03-25 08:57:00.364: E/AndroidRuntime(7910):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
03-25 08:57:00.364: E/AndroidRuntime(7910):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-25 08:57:00.364: E/AndroidRuntime(7910):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-25 08:57:00.364: E/AndroidRuntime(7910):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-25 08:57:00.364: E/AndroidRuntime(7910):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-25 08:57:00.364: E/AndroidRuntime(7910):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-25 08:57:00.364: E/AndroidRuntime(7910):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-25 08:57:00.364: E/AndroidRuntime(7910):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-25 08:57:00.364: E/AndroidRuntime(7910):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-25 08:57:00.364: E/AndroidRuntime(7910):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-25 08:57:00.364: E/AndroidRuntime(7910): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RelativeLayout.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
03-25 08:57:00.364: E/AndroidRuntime(7910):     at com.cartperk.android.cartperk.ui.CameraFragment.setupViews(CameraFragment.java:154)
03-25 08:57:00.364: E/AndroidRuntime(7910):     at com.cartperk.android.cartperk.ui.CameraFragment.onActivityCreated(CameraFragment.java:115)
03-25 08:57:00.364: E/AndroidRuntime(7910):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1508)
03-25 08:57:00.364: E/AndroidRuntime(7910):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
03-25 08:57:00.364: E/AndroidRuntime(7910):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
03-25 08:57:00.364: E/AndroidRuntime(7910):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
03-25 08:57:00.364: E/AndroidRuntime(7910):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1884)
03-25 08:57:00.364: E/AndroidRuntime(7910):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:566)
03-25 08:57:00.364: E/AndroidRuntime(7910):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
03-25 08:57:00.364: E/AndroidRuntime(7910):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
03-25 08:57:00.364: E/AndroidRuntime(7910):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168)
03-25 08:57:00.364: E/AndroidRuntime(7910):     ... 9 more
```

As You i have marked the line with a comment how can i solve this

Comment: Post the logcat so we can spot the cause of your problem

Comment: @Glenn-- I have posted the log cat

Comment: @AbhishekKGowda You're throwing a `NullPointerException` on line `154` in `CameraFragment.setupViews`. It looks like `coachMarkTopLayout` is `null`. Could you post the part of your code where you initialize `coachMarkTopLayout` and that line I mentioned, please?

Comment: @adneal I edit it to the complete code of the java file

Comment: @AbhishekKGowda In the future, you should only paste the code that's most relevant. Is `coachMarkTopLayout` included in the layout `fragment_camera`?

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like you may be initializing `coachMarkTopLayout` incorrectly. When initializing the `View`, you're calling `Activity.findViewById`, but you should be using the `View` bound to your `Fragment`.

- Initialize `coachMarkTopLayout` in `Fragment.onCreateView` using the `View` you return
- Initialize `coachMarkTopLayout` in `Fragment.onViewCreated` - same as above
- Initialize `coachMarkTopLayout` by calling `Fragment.getView` instead of `Fragment.getActivity`